# Accessing Property Bag for List Item using SharePoint Client Object Model or Web Services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, client-side, sharepoint-api

Just to ask if it is possible to access and update properties in the list item's property bag via the SharePoint 2010 client object model?  I can see that it possible to get the web's property bag (but not to set), but can't see any support for the property bag on either the list or list item.

Alternatively, if it is possible to access the propertioes via the SharePoint web services, that would also be useful.

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the thing which you are looking for would be possible [Property Bag](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/1be7cefb-abaa-4f8a-823e-a6d1adcc1e6b)

Comment: Ashutosh, sadly, it looks like you're correct, and this is not yet possible via the client object model.  We could of course make it available through a custom web service.  Adding this functionality as an extension to the current Client object model would be an interesting open source project.  Accepting as answer until someone proves otherwise.